# Can react navigation add costom button on the tab navigator like the pictures

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am facing a problem when using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab). Is it possible to add a custom button on the tab navigator like the following pictures? Do you have any ideas on this? Thanks!!

[image: Tab Navigator with an buttom in the middle]

After click the add button, then a modal pops and the tab navigator hides like:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put whatever you want in the bar by supplying your own implementation of the bar itself.

To use it, you'll have to set the `tabBarComponent` property on the `TabNavigator` configuration:

```
TabNavigator({
  "Tab1": {screen: Tab1},
  "Tab2": {screen: Tab2}
},
{
  tabBarComponent: MyTabBar
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have a try.